# How to inherit and override controller methods in angularjs (java pendent)?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have a simple controller, and would like to introduce a very similar additional controller, but without copying too much code.

```
angular.module('test').controller('parentController', parentController);
parentController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'someService'];

function myController($scope, $location, someService) {
    var params = getQueryString();
    var rsp = executeQuery(params);

    processResponse(rsp);

    function getQueryString() {
        return "?param=1&someparam=2";
    }

    function executeQuery(params) {
        ...
    }

    function processResponse(rsp) {
           //process rsp, convert some parts, and populate model properties, like
           $scope.model.prop1 = rsp.data.prop1;
    }
};
```

Now I'd like to create a controller that is 90% equal to the code of the `parentController`. The main differences:

- get `getQueryString()` should return a different query
- the response properties setter to the `$scope` should contain 1 changed line
- I need additional `filter` functions for inside the new controller, that should only exist for it, but not for the `parentController`.

Coming from `java`, I'd solve this for example with inheritance and overridden methods, like:

```
public cass ParentClass {
    String getQueryString() {
        return "?param=1&someparam=2";
    }
}

public class CustomClass extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    String getQueryString() {
        return "?customparam=1";
    }

    @Override
    void processResponse(rsp) {
         super.processResponse(rsp);
         //read "rsp.paramX" additionally
    }
}
```

But how can I achieve similar with `angularjs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have this structure:

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
   ...
   <div ng-controller="childCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

Since the child controller is under the parent controller scope, it can access all methods/varialbe of the parent's controller, as long as they are defined on the `$scope` of the parent controller (i.e. `$scope.someVar`).

**UPDATE**

If the 2 controllers don't have a parent/child relationship, you'll need to use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), where you will put the shared logic, and then you can define an init function on the service that starts the sequence.

So in you're controllers all you have to do is call `myService.init()` (and maybe pass some parameters)

Comment: I'm not having a nested parent-child structure. The controllers should belong to different views, still are very similar in their logic. When `myController` is run, it acts as some kind of template class, and executes those functions in order: `getQueryString, executeQuery, processResponse`. I'd like to prevent having to repeat those function calls in the child, as their process is already defined in the parent class.

Comment: I mean I'd have to explicit call those methods from the child, even though their execution order is already defined in the parent class.

Comment: So, the only choice here is to define a service that contains the logic and, then you define the functions on both of the controller and use the service: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `$injector` to bring in parent controller properties to the child controller.. your child controller will be something like this:

```
function childController($injector, $scope, someService) {
    // override the method
    this.getQueryString() {
        // new query will be returned
    }

    $injector.invoke(myController, this, {
          $scope: $scope,
          someService: someService
     });
};
```

You can find details of this approach here: https://www.exratione.com/2013/10/two-approaches-to-angularjs-controller-inheritance/

Comment: Does this approach mean any service that is to be injected into `parentController` must also be injected into `childController`, and then assigned inside  `invoke()`?

Comment: yes, you are right.. the service have to be injected to `childController` and then assigned inside the `invoke` method